# Why vim-jsbeautify cannot find module?

Tags: filetype-javascript, plugin-vim-jsbeautify

I'm using vim in cygwin, I want to use https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify to format my javascript code.
but whenever I use `:call JsBeautify()`, there's an error thrown:

```
E117: Unknown function:JsBeautify
```

Whenever I press the keys I mapped for calling JsBeautify, following error occurs:

[image]

Comment: Maybe [it's this issue](https://github.com/maksimr/vim-jsbeautify/issues/63)?

Comment: yeah, maybe, I find that thread too. But to change the vim script of a plugin seems a little too complex for me. So I've chose another approach. I've post an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a solution to resolve this issue directly, but I find another Plugin: https://github.com/Chiel92/vim-autoformat. To use this plugin to format javascript, you have to install a global `js-beautify` node module first:

```
npm install -g js-beautify
```

After the npm module is installed, the plugin will automatically detect it and format js code properly.